# Simple text/string reciprocal cipher DSL which could be random generated?

Tags: string, dsl, encryption

Just to play around, are there any DSL that

- could be generated randomly
- manipulate text or string and restore them
- works like a reciprocal cipher. e.g. If the generated function is `F()`, for every string `s1` you can get scrambled string `s2 = F(s1)`. Then another `G()` could be deduced to reverse `F()`,  which `G(s2) = s1`.
- `F()` and `G()` could be the same or different.

And few additional questions:

- any programming language could deduce reverse functions automatically?
- And make sure generated function `F()` is reversible?

Or any tips where could I start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing

http://strangepaths.com/reversible-computation/2008/01/20/en/

Looks like it's mainly in theory CS, so such DSL is yet to be invented.

So far prolog can do reversible functions

Answer (score 1):

One good starting point would be the Feistel network construction for block ciphers. In essence, it's a basic framework for building an iterated block cipher out of a function. There's very few requirements on the function -- it simply needs to be a function which modifies a piece of the message based on the key. The cipher will work no matter what the function is; the nature of the function will affect the security of the cipher, though.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher

To answer some of your other questions:

> any programming language could deduce reverse functions automatically?

Not in general. Especially because many (most!) functions are not invertible at all.

> And make sure generated function F() is reversible?

Using the Feistel network construction will guarantee this.